# Target final <div> in a set of <div>s using CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<div class="sidebar">1</div>

<div class="sidebar">2</div>

<div class="sidebar">3</div>
```

How do I use CSS to target the last **div** element? I'd like to change the styling if possible.

```
<div class="sidebar">3</div>
```

Sadly, I don't have access to the HTML generated, so is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having access to the HTML your best bet is to go with the `last-child` CSS Selector.

This assumes that the div is the last item in some parent element so that:

```
<div id="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

You could do:

```
#container div:last-child{}
```

Comment: You've made a small mistake. See my comment to @Tom.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.sidebar:last-child`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JJw4w/

That will select your `<div class="sidebar">3</div>` if it's the last element of its parent element.

[`:last-child`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild) is supported in all modern browsers and IE9+ (*not* IE8!).

Comment: This is correct except the div's with the side .sidebar classname would need to be in another container (something like sidebar-container) and then you'd say #sidebar-container:last-child.

Comment: ooh. I didn't know you could use last-child like that. Nice!

Comment: @Tom: No, that's not how it works. `#sidebar-container:last-child` would select `#sidebar-container` if it was the last child of its parent element.

Comment: Epic. Many thanks. I'll use that solution. Nice and clean. Thanks again.

Comment: Check this out, adding a `p` after the sidebar divs breaks the logic: http://jsfiddle.net/JJw4w/12/  @JamieDixon mentioned: "assumes that the div is the last item", that's an important point.

Comment: @cdmo: It's not a bug, it's just how `:last-child` (and similar selectors) behave. `.sidebar:last-child` means "select the last child *if* it's a `.sidebar`", not "select the last `.sidebar` child".

Comment: @thirtydot right, but when you throw in an element after that last `.sidebar` your `.sidebar:last-child` rule no longer works, meaning that last div isn't red. I would have thought it would have stayed red.

Comment: @cdmo: Well, once you add an element after the last `.sidebar`, the last child of the parent element (in your demo, `body`) is no longer a `.sidebar`, it's the (`<p>`) element you just added. So, of course `.sidebar:last-child` no longer matches. I apologize if I seem to be repeating myself :)